# Diagnosing / Debugging I2C comms on the command line

Tags: gpio, i2c

This is sort of a vague question, and I apologize for that. I am trying to gain enough understanding and context to ask a more detailed one.  But here goes:

**Q: To what extent is the I2C bus self documenting?**

I can run `i2cdetect -y 1` and see my device at address 0x40 (I know this is my device since it goes away if I unplug it).

But if I were unable to unplug it, would I be able to query it for a name in a standardized manner?

If I wanted to read from it, with no documentation, is there a default "read" register?

so to recap the question: can I ask devices on the bus "who are you" and "what values do you have?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you've not done enough research to ask a succinct question. Suggest you **delete this question** ASAP, and come back after you've read a bit on how I2C works.

Comment: If you disconnect an I2C device the system it was connected to will know precisely nothing about the disconnected device. There's no memory function, it's a read a device while it's connected bus (just like any other bus and any other interface).